# Declaring a list in a class's header file

Tags: c++, list

So, i have to write a program in cpp, but i have to write it with objective paradigm. Aaand i stuck with declaring a list. So i have this, simplifying as much as possible:

```
    class A{
      private:
        list<B> *listName;
      public:
        A();
        ~A();
    };
```

And it gives me six errors, mostly missing semicolons from line with list declaration and

```
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

It's propably a simple syntax error, but i can't find anything for a while.
Declaring a instance of B there works.
Declaring such list in main() works too. 
Oh, and IDE seems to find it correct, the compiling throws errors

Comment: What is B declared as?

Comment: And did you include  <list> and using namespace std; ?

else you have to 

#include <list>

std::list<b> *listName

Comment: B is another class, but a simple int doesnt work neither.
Yes, i include. IDE would underline it with red if something would be wrong with includes i guess.

Comment: https://ideone.com/Tu3Svs  try have a look at this code

Comment: Do you have a proper forward declaration of the B class, in scope?

Comment: It's impossible to know when we don't know more about the code. Also which compiler and IDE do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015.
B is not implemented yet, just empty constructor and destructor, but it doesnt matter as long as the list of integers doesnt work as well.
The problem is the code works if i paste it to same cpp file the main() is, but stops when placed in header file of the class. And yes, i have to put classes in separate files, its a requirement of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are correct about the int won't work either in your code piece. Im almost sure you either don't include the list correct or you don't use the standard namespace correct.

```
#include <list>

   class A{
      private:
        std::list<int> *listName;
      public:
        A();
        ~A();
    };
```

Include the  and remember to use

```
std::list<Type>
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Yes, it is written in exactly same way as in my code. And yes, it works if placed in main.cpp, but stops when i put it into A.h. And yes, i have #nclude "A.h" in main.cpp.

Comment: Ok, i found the answer. I had all includes and using namspace std with #pragma once in a separate header file i included in every other file to simply not paste all those everywhere. Compilator has not seen the namespace line from there.